# The flask api endpoint returns the correct response with postman but not with the browser(chrome)

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors, flask-restful, flask-cors

The first file is app.py containing the flask api's

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property
from flask_restx import Api, Resource, fields
from flask_cors import CORS
import numpy as np
import sys
import pickle

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Api(app = flask_app, 
          version = "1.0", 
          title = "Boston House Classification", 
          description = "Predict house price")

CORS(flask_app)

name_space = app.namespace('prediction', description='Prediction APIs')

model = app.model('Prediction params', 
                  {'x1': fields.Float(required = True, 
                                               description="x1", 
                                               help="salary cannot be blank"),
                  'x2': fields.Float(required = True, 
                                               description="x2", 
                                               help="age cannot be blank"),
                  })
filename = "finalized_model.sav"
classifier = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

@name_space.route("/")
class MainClassFirst(Resource):

    def get(self):
        response = "hello"
        return make_response(jsonify({"result":response}))

@name_space.route("/predict/")
class MainClass(Resource):

    # def options(self):
    #   response = make_response()
    #   response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    #   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*")
    #   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "*")
    #   return response

    @app.expect(model)      
    
    def post(self): 
        formData = request.json
        data = [val for val in formData.values()]
        print(data, file = sys.stderr)
        newarr = np.array(data).reshape(1,-1).astype(np.float)
        
        prediction = classifier.predict(newarr)
        res = str(prediction[0])
        
        response = jsonify({
            "statusCode": 200,
            "status": "Prediction made",
            "result": res
            })
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
```

Here I tried using CORS from the flask_cors and also tried to handle it myself using options method(which is commented in the code).Also the App.js file of the react app making the call is given below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FormContainer extends Component {
  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    
      this.state = {
          formControls: {
              x1: {
                value: ''
              },
              x2: {
                value: ''
              },
              submit: {
                value: ''
              },
              answer: {
                value: ''
              }
          }
      }
    
  }
  
  changeHandler = event => {
      
      const name = event.target.name;
      const value = event.target.value;
    
      this.setState({
        formControls: {
            ...this.state.formControls,
            [name]: {
            ...this.state.formControls[name],
            value
          }
        }
      });
  }

  submitHandler = event => {
      
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ x1: this.state.formControls.x1.value,
        x2: this.state.formControls.x2.value, })
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/prediction/predict/', requestOptions)
      .then(async response => {
          const data = await response.json();

          // check for error response
          if (!response.ok) {
              // get error message from body or default to response status
              const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
              console.log(error)
              return Promise.reject(error);
          }

          
          console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        
          console.error('There was an error!', error);
      });
}

  
   render() {
      return (
          
          <form>
  <div className="form-group row">
    <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">x1</label>
    <div className="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" 
                     name="x1" 
                     value={this.state.formControls.x1.value} 
                     onChange={this.changeHandler} 
              />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group row">
    <label htmlFor="inputPassword3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">x2</label>
    <div className="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" 
                     name="x2" 
                     value={this.state.formControls.x2.value} 
                     onChange={this.changeHandler} 
              />
    </div>
  </div>

  <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here..." name="answer" 
                     defaultValue={this.state.formControls.answer.value} 
                      readOnly></input>
  
  <div className="form-group row">
    <div className="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" name="submit" 
                     value={this.state.formControls.submit.value} 
                     onClick={this.submitHandler}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>      
      );
  }

}


export default FormContainer;
```

[The networks tab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iugA0.png)

[flask terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8lhP.png)

I am new to react and flask.
A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set-up CORS for your Flask application to accept ajax calls from `localhost`:

https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I already did `pip install -U flask-cors`. That's why i could import CORS . I can't see any more set-up steps.